# Is there a way to fetch JSON data into a data tag to show in a chart in React Native?

Tags: json, react-native, charts, dataset, fetch

I want to dynamically show a chart based on JSON data in my React Native app. How do I parse my JSON data into a data attribute?

The chart works with data from an array, for example:

```
data={{
    labels: ["06-06-2019 17:17:58",
        "06-06-2019 17:19:06",
        "06-06-2019 17:20:07",
    datasets: [{
        data: [
            28.76,
            24.77,
            24.68,
        ]
    }]
}}
```

I have figured out how to get my JSON data in an array. I can console.warn this and it's all fine. Yet it does not work in the data set.

In the following code I fetch my JSON data and push it in a this.state variable (either labelsTest or valuesTest based on the data).
In the data constant I create the set the data needed for the lineChart. This.state.labelsTest works fine, yet this.state.valuesTest gives me an error:
Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by: RNSVGPath

null

For input string: "l"

I've tried storing my this.state.valuesArray data in a local array, yet this gives me the same exact error.

Hard coded data works fine. If I for example take my commented testArrayDing array, it works without any problems.

I've also tried converting my JSON data to ints because, who knows, it might fetch them as strings for some reason. This didn't work either.

Something I've noticed is that my console.warn gives me an empty array and then a second after, the correctly filled arrays. I've no idea if this has anything to do with my error.

```js
class GraphScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        labelsTest: [],
        valuesTest: [],
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch("https://testrest1.herokuapp.com/testjson")
      .then((result)=>result.json())
      .then((res)=>{
        this.setState({

          labelsTest: res.map(obj => {
            return obj.label;
          }),

          valuesTest: res.map(obj => {
            return obj.value;
          }),
        });
      })
    }

  render() {
    var valuesArray = [];

    let iterable = this.state.valuesTest;
    for (let value of iterable) {
      valuesArray.push(value);
      console.warn(value);
    }

    console.warn("ARRAYYY = " + valuesArray);

    const data = {
      labels: this.state.labelsTest,
      datasets: [{
        data: testArrayDing,
      }]
    }

    // var testArrayDing = [20,125,10];

    return(
      <View>
        <LineChart
          data={data}
          width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // from react-native
          height={220}
          //yAxisLabel={'$'}
          chartConfig={{
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            backgroundGradientFrom: '#fff',
            backgroundGradientTo: '#fff',
            decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
            color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(3, 169, 244, ${opacity})`,
            strokeWidth: 4,
          }}
          bezier
          style={{
            marginVertical: 8,
            color: "#000000",
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: you should write code for your data to change it to LineChart data format.
edit your question and include example data that I can help

Comment: @SiSa I've updated my first post with some more information and things I've tried.